# Cannot Add Option List to Multiple Select jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create multi select option list like [this](http://demos.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/) example plugin. The option list is populated using ajax call to the database. The ajax call works fine but the option list is not being populated. I also followed this [guide](https://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/). Any help highly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="langOpt">Select Option</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
    <!--option list-->
    </select>
</div>
```

Plugin Call

```
<script>
$('select[multiple]').multiselect();
</script>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$('#langOpt').click(function () {

      $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType :'json',
            url : "<?php echo base_url('registration/get_opton_list') ?>",
            success : function(data) {
              $('#langOpt').html('');
              jQuery(data).each(function(i, item){
                $('#langOpt').append("<option value='"+ item.optionId+"'>" + item.optionName+ "</option>");

                //this ensure the ajax call, values print on console
                console.log(item.optionId);
                console.log(item.optionName);
              });

            }

          });
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE:
Calling plugin into ajax success gives an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):190)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success ((index):183)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):190
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
success @ (index):183
c @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
l @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):176
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: call the plugin in ajax success.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour not woking.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour please check on update

Comment: Try first destroy the plugin (search the docs for proper function) when plugin is destroyed you can use `.empty()` same as `html('')` and after you add options call it again. Also make sure that you loaded the plugin and it don't give 500 or 404 error. Open dev tools (F12) and check in console if `$.fn.multiselect` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
jQuery(data).each(function(i, item){
    $('#langOpt').append("<option value='"+ item.optionId+"'>" + item.optionName+ "</option>");
    //this ensure the ajax call, values print on console
    console.log(item.optionId);
    console.log(item.optionName);
});
```

↓

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $('#langOpt').append("<option value='"+ item.optionId+"'>" + item.optionName+ "</option>");
    //this ensure the ajax call, values print on console
    console.log(item.optionId);
    console.log(item.optionName);
});
```

Take a look here: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/

Best regards,

Brhaka

Comment: Are you sure that Json data is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

Please apply multiselect plugin again in ajax respose(sucess)

```
  <script>
    $('#langOpt').click(function () {

     $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType :'json',
        url : "<?php echo base_url('registration/get_opton_list') ?>",
        success : function(data) {
          $('#langOpt').html('');
          jQuery(data).each(function(i, item){
            $('#langOpt').append("<option value='"+ item.optionId+"'>" + item.optionName+ "</option>");
            $('#langOpt').multiselect();
            //this ensure the ajax call, values print on console
            console.log(item.optionId);
            console.log(item.optionName);
          });

        }

      });
});
```

Note : Make sure the CSS and JS of plugin is added successfully on your page.

Comment: please check on update. CSS and JS already added successfully.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle so that we can check the issue.